# How to pull file from user class parse swift

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, pfuser, pffile

In my app, when a user signs up, he/she signs up, an image is added to the user class. The code used to do this is...

```
    var newUser = PFUser()
    let imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(self.imageView.image)
    let imageFile = PFFile(data: imageData)
    newUser.setObject(imageFile, forKey: "image")
    newUser.signUpInBackgroundWithBlock({
        (success, error) -> Void in
    })
```

Later in my app, I want to pull that picture to put it into a UIImageView. The way I tried to do it was this.

```
    var user = PFUser.currentUser()  //Error on this line
    let profileImage = user["image"] as! PFFile
```

However, this returns the error "AnyObject? is not convertible to PFFile". I would like to know how I can retrieve the file with the key "image" from the user class. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Is the error on the PFFile line? or on the user = PFUser.currentUser() line?

Comment: The PFUser.currentUser() line @Jbryson

Answer (score 1):

An image is stored in parse as a datafile. To retrieve the image again from parse, and load it to you UIImage. You need to convert the image

```
var user = PFUser.currentUser()
let userImageFile = user["image"] as PFFile
userImageFile.getDataInBackgroundWithBlock {
(imageData: NSData!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
if !error {
    let image = UIImage(data:imageData)
  }
}
```

And change the `let image` to the image you want to load your image.

Comment: I know how to retrieve it, but my issue is that I do not know how to access the user class. The line var user = PFUser.currentUser() does not work. @MrUziBazooka

Comment: @AidanKaiser try to change "var user = PFUser.currentUser()" to "var user = PFUser().currentUser"

Comment: Can you get any infomation from the currentUser or is it just the image that is the problem?

Comment: I can't get any info about the user, the image is totally fine @MrUziBazooka

Comment: Okey. And you can see the user in the backend after it has been created?